# Как средствами Wordpress создать файлы для локализации темы (.pot, .po, .mo)?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины, wp-plugin, wordpress-multisite

Нашел плагин Loco Translate, однако при попытке создать файл перевода, он не находит конструкции __('text', 'theme') в папке темы.

Есть подробная инструкция, как создать эти файлы, или нужен другой плагин?

Comment: По сей день. если сталкиваюсь, пользую [poeditor](https://poedit.net/download), а внутрь самого сайта стараюсь лишних расширений не пихать.

Comment: Я уже полдня пытаюсь это сделать при помощи poeditor, у меня ничего не выходит...

Comment: Значит что-то делаете не так, поищите инструкции, да хоть видео на ютубе.

Comment: неужели никто не поможет?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В Wordpress есть возможность работы через командную строку

https://wp-cli.org/

В нем , кроме всяких полезных вещей, есть возможность создания файлов переводов из командной строки

```
# Create a POT file for the WordPress plugin/theme in the current directory
$ wp i18n make-pot . languages/my-plugin.pot
```

https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/i18n/make-pot/

Comment: Есть, файл создался, как его теперь можно использовать?

Comment: @Сергей потом можно создавать языковые файлы уже с помощью плагинов в админке. например, плагин Loco Translate

Comment: большая просьба, по пунктам опишите, пожалуйста, куда нажимать в этом плагине, я уже полдня мучаюсь...

Comment: @Сергей https://localise.biz/wordpress/plugin/manual/msginit

Comment: @Сергей полное описание https://localise.biz/wordpress/plugin#guides